# How to create a new item as a link to document in folder in a document library csom powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I have a documentset inside a folder.And I have to create a new item using content type "Link To document" which redirects to that documentset, in other folders  using **CSOM powershell**. As this an urgent requirement. Can you provide me the solution ASAP.

Thanks

Comment: “Can you provide me the solution ASAP.” No. Can you show what you’ve tried and where it isn’t working/where you’re stuck.

Comment: I did not find links to implement this functionality in csom powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PnP call will be quite easy to do so.

```
$stream = [IO.MemoryStream]::new([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("[InternetShortcut]URL=your file URL"))
Add-PnPFile -FileName "your file name.url" -Folder "folder path in your site" -Stream $stream -Values @{_ShortcutUrl="your file url"}
```

Start using PNP:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VLGj-kV0Pw